# Java APT how to break a maven1 build when some apt condition are true

Tags: java, annotations, maven

I have an APT processor that display warnings on some conditions.
My project is using a maven1 build calling ant:apt

How to make maven fails when warning conditions are met ? (the processor can be modified)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation processor needs to create a message of Kind `ERROR`. This results in a Compilation Failure, which in turn will abort the ant build (unless the `failonerror` parameter of the [ant javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) is set to `false`). (And this in turn should fail the maven task)

```
processingEnvironment
    .getMessager()
    .printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "your error message here");
```

(Acquire the ProcessingEnvironment through the processor's [init method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#init%28javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment%29))

**Reference:**

- [ProcessingEnvironment.getMessager()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment.html#getMessager%28%29)
- [Messager.printMessage(Kind, CharSequence)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html#printMessage%28javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/Diagnostic.Kind.html#ERROR)

Comment: Thanks for having answering this rather old still opened question !